# Drupal: Extended user forms?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I want to extend user forms in Drupal (to allow them to insert more data, such as Company name, surname, nationality.. etc

should I search for an additional module ? Or is it already embed in drupal ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/profile You can extend the user form with additional fields.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Profile module suggested by txwikinger, you may be interested by the [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module. It allows you to use node as user profile. Enabling CCK-drived profile form.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fond of coding, you could do something like our [drupal company](http://wearepropeople.com/) solution to modify the profile template to just print the field instead of the form element. I haven't tried, but I think you might be able to use hook_form_alter to set the field properties to disabled. It would be nice to have a read-only option in the permissions.
We added something similar to this in the template:

profile_givenname." ".$account->profile_surname; ?>

```
<div class="field_team">Email: <a href="mailto:<?php echo $account->mail; ?>"><?php echo $account->mail; ?></a></div>
<div class="field_team">Team: <?php print check_plain($account->profile_role); ?></div>
<div class="field_memberSince">Member Since: <?php echo $account->content['summary']['member_for']['#value']; ?></div>
<div class="field_location">Location: <?php echo check_plain($account->profile_location);?></div>
```